# Send an XMPP message with Python

Tags: python, xmpp, sendmessage

I'm trying to send an XMPP message using Python but I can't get it to work. It seems to be failing at the authentication step. I took this example from a previous question and set up a gmail account for testing.

```
import xmpp

username = 'randomtest603@gmail.com'
passwd = 'ThePass123'
to='randomtest604@gmail.com'
msg='hello :)'

client = xmpp.Client('gmail.com')
client.connect(server=('talk.google.com',5223))
client.auth(username, passwd, 'botty')
client.sendInitPresence()
message = xmpp.Message(to, msg)
message.setAttr('type', 'chat')
client.send(message)
```

There's lots of debug output but this is the part that tells me it fails

```
DEBUG: socket       sent  <auth xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-sasl" mechanism="PLAIN">cmFuZG9tdGVzdDYwM0BnbWFpbC5jb21AZ21haWwuY29tAHJhbmRvbXRlc3Q2MDNAZ21haWwuY29tAFRoZVBhc3MxMjM=</auth>
DEBUG: socket       got   <failure xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-sasl">
  <invalid-authzid/>
  </failure>
  </stream:stream>
DEBUG: dispatcher   ok    Got urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-sasl/failure stanza
DEBUG: dispatcher   ok    Dispatching failure stanza with type-> props->  [u'urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-sasl'] id->None
DEBUG: sasl         error Failed SASL authentification: <invalid-authzid />
```

But then I also get this at the end

```
DEBUG: socket       sent  <presence id="2" />
DEBUG: socket       sent  <message to="randomtest604@gmail.com" type="chat" id="3">
  <body>hello :)</body>
  </message>
```

I've tried this xmpppy and sleekxmpp and the result is the same. This area is new to me so I'm probably making a newbie mistake, anyone have any ideas?

thanks

Comment: What XMPP module are you using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is not python-specific nor library specific. When you call `xmpp.Client('gmail.com')` you are specifying the domain part of the username as "gmail.com". Therefore, you should omit that from the username you're using.

Amend your third line to this:

```
username = 'randomtest603'
```

It should work(I tried it with my own account after generating an application specific password for this test and it worked only if I omitted the '@gmail.com' from the username, otherwise I got the same error as you).

Comment: Glad to have been of help :)

Comment: @entropy, I got the same problem.I have done as you said but still having that error.What to do..?

Comment: @Mulagala can't tell for sure without seeing any of your code

Comment: @entropy, The code is exactly what we seen above question and edited as you said

Comment: Are you 100% sure you have the right credentials? Because I have no clue what's going wrong in your case